Compare vba .Now vs cell Today formula
I have a script that timestamp whenever I put data, but sometimes I have to change the date manually.
The problem is when I have to apply a formula between these 2, the automatic timestamp and the manual date, for example "if is the same date", it return false value for the same date, even when it is in the same format. I know it is something with the script set as "as string" but I don't know how to fix it
I need to do for example:
=IF(J2=TODAY();1;0)
"J2" is the automatic timestamp with .Now by the following script
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Const ColumnsToMonitor As String = "k:z"
  Const DateColumn As String = "j"
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  
  
  If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(ColumnsToMonitor)) Is Nothing Then
    Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Columns(DateColumn)).Value = Format(Now, "ddd d/mm")
  End If
       
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

how to fix the script so I can compare the automatic timestamp with =Now to a manual date or =Today formula

Your problem is possibly because TODAY() returns a date only, but Now returns a datetime. You can force the result of Now to drop the date by using CDATE(INT(Now))

The following code line populates cells in column J with text (String) instead of a date/value. As a result, J2=TODAY() evaluates to False. A quick fix is to update the formula to =IF(J2=TEXT(TODAY(), "ddd d/mm"),1,0).
Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Columns(DateColumn)).Value = Format(Now, "ddd d/mm")


I recommend updating your script to populate the cells in column J with actual dates. Here are the suggested changes:

Set Application.EnableEvents = False as the first setting.
Use Date to return today's date instead of Now.
Apply a date format to column J to ensure consistency.

Your formulas should work correctly after applying the changes.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Const ColumnsToMonitor As String = "k:z"
  Const DateColumn As String = "j"
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  
  If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(ColumnsToMonitor)) Is Nothing Then
        With Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Columns(DateColumn))
            .Value = Date
            .NumberFormat = "ddd d/mm"
        End With
  End If
       
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

